# What is the replacement of html5smartimage xtype in touch UI

Tags: aem, aem-6, aem-touch-ui

I have a need to allow the authors to be able to do image cropping while authoring. This was easily done using html5smartimage xtype in classic UI. However, in touch UI there seems no replacement for the same. Is there a way to achieve this.

**Note:** This requirement is for the authoring and cropping of the image in the page properties dialog, so the inplaceediting of image cant be used there.

Answer (score 2):

only replacement available is resourceType - cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog/fileupload
with attribute useHTML5 = true

example can be found under - /apps/core/wcm/components/image/v1/image

cropping option is only availabe for inplace editing.